# Настройки редиректа для строки с параметрами

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Нужно сделать редирект со страниц http://www.mysite.ru/news/?PAGEN_1=1 и http://www.mysite.ru/news/?&PAGEN_1=1 на страницу http://www.mysite.ru/news/, а со всех страниц с урлом, заканчивающимся на ?&PAGEN_1=n на аналогичный урл, только заканчивающийся на ?PAGEN_1=n. Аналогично для раздела /articles/2/

редиректы в htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^PAGEN_1=1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^news/$ http:/www.mysite.ru/news/$ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^&PAGEN_1=1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^news/$ http:/www.mysite.ru/news/$ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^&PAGEN_1=([2-9]*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)$ http:/www.mysite.ru/news/?PAGEN_1=%1 [R=301,L]



RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^PAGEN_1=1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^articles/2/$ http:/www.mysite.ru/articles/2/$ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^&PAGEN_1=1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^articles/2/$ http:/www.mysite.ru/articles/2/$ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^&PAGEN_1=([2-9]*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^articles/2/(.*)$ http:/www.mysite.ru/articles/2/?PAGEN_1=%1 [R=301,L]
```

Для раздела news всё работает как надо, а вот со страниц http://www.mysite.ru/articles/2/?PAGEN_1=1 и http://www.mysite.ru/articles/2/?&PAGEN_1=1 выкидывает на раздел http://www.mysite.ru/articles/ (такой раздел на сайте тоже есть). Не могу понять, почему, и как правильно написать редирект?